# PHP: Check if a loaded TLS certificate is trusted

Tags: php, ssl, certificate

The program fetches a TLS certificate chain from a server and does several checks. It should check if the last part of the chain points to a trusted certificate. Here is an excerpt show the relevant part:

```
$g = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array(
  "capture_peer_cert" => true,
  "capture_peer_cert_chain" => true,
  "peer_name" => $domain,
  "verify_peer" => false,
  "verify_peer_name" => false,
  "SNI_enabled" => true,
  )));
$r = @stream_socket_client($url, $errno, $errstr, 5, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $g);
$cont = stream_context_get_params($r);
$certchain = &$cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate_chain"];
$ChainAuthorityIds = array();
```

Snip: Now, there follows some longer code that fills up the array `ChainAuthorityIds` like that: 0-indexed each index contains an array of two fields: `subject` containing the key Id of the subject field, and `authority`, containing the key Id of the authority field. This is done by using `openssl_x509_parse()`.

Afterwards, we can check for correct order like this:

```
$correctorder = true;
$previous_authority = null;
foreach ($ChainAuthorityIds as $num => &$details) {
  if ($previous_authority !== null) {
    if ($details['subject'] != $previous_authority) $correctorder = false;
  }
  $previous_authority = $details['authority'];
}
unset($details);
```

So, in `$ChainAuthorityIds[count($ChainAuthorityIds) - 1]['authority']` must be the key Id of a certificate that is stored in OpenSSL's directory of trusted roots. How can I check if this key is part of this truststore? Also, I want to explicitly load this certificate (possibly with something like `openssl_x509_parse()`) into memory to check its validity period.

**PS:** If the chain is over-complete, and the last certificate is the root, then it contains an empty string as authority Id key. This case is properly handled in my program, but for sake of simplicity not shown in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Suprisingly, the answer is quite simple. OpenSSL holds its truststore in a directory containing each root certificate as PEM file - one certificate per file. So, all that needs to be done is finding out which directory this is. This can be done by using the PHP command `openssl_get_cert_locations()`. It returns an array, of which the index `default_cert_dir` holds the said directory name.

```
$locations = opnenssl_get_cert_locations();
$pemfiles = glob($locations['default_cert_dir'] . '/*.pem');
foreach ($permfiles as $pemfile) {
  $rootcert = openssl_x509_parse(openssl_x509_read($pemfile));
  // do something with $rootcert
}
```